# Best way to use Yahoo-Finance Python API

Tags: python, regex, yahoo-finance

The output of historical data using the Python Yahoo-Finance API is structured as follows:

```
{u'Adj_Close': u'63.209999',
 u'Close': u'63.209999',
 u'Date': u'2015-08-27',
 u'High': u'63.259998',
 u'Low': u'61.080002',
 u'Open': u'61.459999',
 u'Symbol': u'CAM',
 u'Volume': u'22808600'}
```

What's the best way to handle this data? For example, how can I access the Close price of 63.209999? Should I use a regex?

Answer (score 0):

As shown you have a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries); use the keys to access values in the dictionary:

```
>>> d={u'Adj_Close': u'63.209999',
...  u'Close': u'63.209999',
...  u'Date': u'2015-08-27',
...  u'High': u'63.259998',
...  u'Low': u'61.080002',
...  u'Open': u'61.459999',
...  u'Symbol': u'CAM',
...  u'Volume': u'22808600'}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> d['Close']
u'63.209999'
>>> d['High']
u'63.259998'
```

Probably, however, you have a JSON string. If so you can convert the JSON string to a dictionary using `json.loads()`:

```
>>> s = '{"High": "63.259998", "Volume": "22808600", "Low": "61.080002", "Date": "2015-08-27", "Close": "63.209999", "Symbol": "CAM", "Open": "61.459999", "Adj_Close": "63.209999"}'
>>> import json
>>> d = json.loads(s)
>>> d['Close']
u'63.209999'
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is an excellent library to handle such tabular problem.

You can do like this

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> data = {u'Adj_Close': u'63.209999',
...         u'Close': u'63.209999',
...         u'Date': u'2015-08-27',
...         u'High': u'63.259998',
...         u'Low': u'61.080002',
...         u'Open': u'61.459999',
...         u'Symbol': u'CAM',
...         u'Volume': u'22808600'}
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data.items())
>>> print df.head()
        0           1
0    High   63.259998
1  Volume    22808600
2     Low   61.080002
3    Date  2015-08-27
4   Close   63.209999
```

**NOTE**: Be careful with  `u'Symbol': u'CAM'` because it is a [scalar value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)).